# $2^{(x+2)} + 2^{(x-1)} =18$ about options of resolution (integer solutions)

Tags: functions

I was try to solve this equation
$2^{(x+2)} + 2^{(x-1)} =18$
by many ways, when I find that : (image) Is it right that way?
Because, solving by system, I find "$2$" like a answer too. But can be just a coincidence.

[image: It is ok to do?]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: Divide both sides by 2^(x-1) and simplify...

Comment: Put $x-1=X$ then $2^{X+3}+2^X=2^X(8+1)=2\cdot3^3$ Thus $X=1\iff x=2$

Answer (score 1):

```
2^(x + 2) + 2^(x - 1) == 18

2^3*2^(x - 1) + 2^(x - 1) == 18

8*2^(x - 1) + 2^(x - 1) == 18

9*2^(x - 1) == 18

2^(x - 1) == 2

x - 1 == 1

x == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WolframAlpha["Solve 2^(x+2)+2^(x-1)=18",PodStates->{"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

to this end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Factor[2^(x + 2) + 2^(x - 1) == 18]
```

(* 9 2^(-1 + x) == 18 *)

```
Reduce[2^(x - 1) == 2, x, Complexes]
```

(* C[1] [Element] Integers && x == 2 + (2 I [Pi] C[1])/Log[2] *)

That is already the solution from WolframAlpha but with the division of Log[4]/Log[2] done.

Mind this is a solution path selecting consequently Mathematica built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

```
FindInstance[2^(x + 2) + 2^(x - 1) == 18, x, Reals] // Flatten
(* {x -> 2} *)

Reduce[2^(x + 2) + 2^(x - 1) == 18, x, Reals]
(* x == 2 *)

Solve[2^(x + 2) + 2^(x - 1) == 18, x, Reals] // Flatten
(* {x -> 2} *)
```

all work.